# How to create a add image input in formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

I want to create a customized input field in formik for an image upload. I want to pass binary file data to backend, but it is taking the file location. Can you help me?

Here is the boilerplate code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useField } from 'formik';
import { Form, Col, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';

const FileInput = ({ label, ...props }) => {
  const [field, meta] = useField(props);
  return (
    <>
      <Form.Group as={Row} controlId="">
        <Form.Label htmlFor={props.id || props.name} column sm={3}>
          {label}
        </Form.Label>
        {props.initalImage ? (
          <img height="35px" alt={props.initalImage} src={props.initalImage} />
        ) : null}
        <Col sm={4}>
          <Form.Control
            {...field}
            {...props}
            accept={props.accept}
            isValid={meta.touched && !meta.error}
            isInvalid={Boolean(meta.touched && meta.error)}
          />
          {meta.error ? (
            <>
              <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                {meta.error}
              </Form.Control.Feedback>
            </>
          ) : null}
          <span className="form-text text-muted mt-3">
            Please choose an icon which is min. 256x256px.
          </span>
        </Col>
      </Form.Group>
    </>
  );
};

export { FileInput };
```

and here is where I am calling it:

```
            <FileInput
              label="Light Icon:"
              type="file"
              name="lightIcon"
              accept="image/x-png"
              onBlur
            />
```

I tried this but it is not working:

```
        <FileInput
          label="Light Icon:"
          type="file"
          name="lightIcon"
          accept="image/x-png"
          onBlur
          onChange={(e) => {
            setFieldValue('lightIcon', e.target.files[0]);
          }}
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick with `<input>` elements with `type="file"` is that we shouldn't set their value manually, it actually uses it's own mechanism along with browser's security implementations and set it itself on the client's machine.
So we don't have access to the real path of the file on the disk, instead we are able to use a [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) object to asynchronously read contents of the file as blob of buffer and pass it to our `parent` component.

> There are cases where you can change file input's value
> programmatically, like to null to reset your input.

The following example implements an `UploadFiled` component with `type="file"` get wrapped with a custom Field component, whenever child component getting update, a file is being uploaded, and parent component will knows and starts reading the contents of the specified Blob, once finished, the result attribute contains a data url representing the file's data will set as it's value. It currently accepts an image base on the validation that is set for it using [Yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup).

The traditional `application/json` type won’t help in uploading the image to your server, the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) will. You need to write your `handleSubmit()` using the form data and pass the values handled by Formik.
Check my [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-multi-step-file-upload-with-preview-formik-9g6n4) for the working demo.

```js
const handleSubmit= () => {
    // Create an object of formData
    const formData = new FormData();

    // Update the formData object
    formData.append("myFile", file, file.name);

    // Details of the uploaded file
    console.log(file);

    // Request made to the backend api
    // Send formData object
    axios.post("api/uploadfile", formData);
  };
```

```js
// UploadForm.jsx
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Field, useField } from "formik";
import { Grid, FormHelperText } from "@material-ui/core";
import UploadField from "../../FormFields/UploadField";
import Thumb from "../Helper/Thumb";

const ImageForm = (props) => {
  const {
    formField: { image }
  } = props;

  const [field, meta, helper] = useField(image.name);
  const { touched, error } = meta;
  const { setValue } = helper;
  const isError = touched && error && true;
  const { value } = field;

  const [fileName, setFileName] = useState(value.name);
  const [file, setFile] = useState(value.file);
  const [src, setSrc] = useState(value.src);
  const _onChange = (e) => {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    let file = e.target.files[0];
    if (file) {
      reader.onloadend = () => setFileName(file.name);
      if (file.name !== fileName) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        setSrc(reader);
        setFile(file);
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (file && fileName && src) {
      setValue({ file: file, src: src, name: fileName });
      console.log(fileName);
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [src, fileName, file]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Grid container spacing={3} justify="center" alignItems="center">
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <label>
            {image.label}
          </label>
          <br />
          <div
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              justifyContent: "flex-start",
              fontSize: "1.2em"
            }}
          >
            <Field
              variant="outlined"
              field={field}
              component={UploadField}
              onChange={_onChange}
              isError={isError}
            />
            {isError && <FormHelperText color={"red"}>{error}</FormHelperText>}
          </div>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>{file && src && <Thumb file={file} src={src}></Thumb>}</Grid>
      </Grid>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default ImageForm;
```

```html
import React from "react";
import { Field } from "formik";

const UploadField = ({
  field,
  form: { touched, errors },
  name,
  label,
  isError,
  ...props
}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Field
        variant="outlined"
        name="uploader"
        title={label}
        type={"file"}
        {...props}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default UploadField;
```